# vaadin and google app engine for java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, vaadin

I am trying to create the UI for a Google App Engine for Java web app

(1) I tried creating a new Vaadin project- but when I try to run it I always get an error- Google.AppEngine.Datastore class is not recognized. How do I fix this error

(2) I would like to use Vaadin in an existing Google App Engine web application- how do I do this without going through the new Vaadin Project Wizard? How do I create a vaadin based UI in an existing google app engine application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) I asked the same question and the answer from one of the vaadin team was:

> It might not be so easy to add a Vaadin application to a GWT application. The other way around is then again possible. Maybe you could keep the two applications separate and just embed with an iframe or div the Vaadin app.

https://vaadin.com/de/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/570153